# I am not able to clear me textare value after the ajax is submited successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

```
  $(document).on('click','#commentsubmitimage',function(e) {
    console.log("beni");
    e.preventDefault();


     var content =$('#commenttext').val();
    console.log(content);

    var imageid = $('#imagecomid').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/user/postcoment/" + imageid,

      data:{
        contenta:content
      },
      success: function(data) {
      // have try this
       document.getElementById(commenttext).innerHTML = '';
     // have try this
       $('#commenttext').val('');
 },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }

    });
  });
```

I want to clear my textareaa with id ="commenttext" i have try all the methods and it doesnt happen nothing any suggest ?

Comment: Have you verified that the success callback is executing?

Comment: Make sure the success function has been called. Besides `commenttext` was not defined.

Comment: i verified now and is not being executing how can i fix it so it callback is executing ?

Comment: What's the response code on the request in your network console?

Comment: it doesnt show nowthing , i made a console.log() in my success callback and it doesnt show nothing

Comment: No, crack open your developer tools (F12 usually), go to the network tab, make your ajax request happen, and look at the request.  It will have a response code and you can see other details about the request for debugging purposes.

Comment: i fixed it now , i had forget to call my success callback in my post route , thanks for the help all !

Answer (score 0):

if your success  call back working correctly then write

```
success: function(data) {
  alert("working");
  $("#commenttext").val("");
```